# Plot graph with 2 variables in matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, plot

I'm planning to plot a graph of velocity against time using matlab. The change of time is `0.05` and total time `15`. When time change, the graph will change and save a figure of that. I had mat file which contained all the data for time and velocity.

E.g, `t=0`, `v=0`, plot and save, `t=0.05`, `v=1`, plot and save until `t=15`.

I tried to use `v=v+1` (which acts like `i++`) but failed to read the value of `v` in 2nd row. Any other method to do so?

Thank You.
The code is

```
i = 001
dt = t(2,1) - t(1,1);
k = dt*(i-1);
filename1 = 'front_data';
matFileName = sprintf('%s.mat', filename1);
matData = load(matFileName);
t = matData.time;
fv = matData.front_velocity;
fig = figure%('visible', 'off');
s = t(1,1);
fv = fv(1,1);
lot (s,fv,'*')
pic_filename = sprintf('front_data%02d.jpeg', k);
print(fig,pic_filename,'-djpeg')

istart = 002
iend = 301

for i = istart:iend
    k = dt*(i-1);
    t = t+dt
    filename1 = 'front_data';
    matFileName = sprintf('%s.mat', filename1);
    matData = load(matFileName);
    t = matData.time;
    fv = matData.front_velocity;

    v = fv(1,1);
    v = v+1;
    h = figure
    axis([0 15 0 0.6])
    plot(t,v,'*')
    pic_filename = sprintf('front_data%02d.jpeg', k);
    print(h,pic_filename,'-djpeg')
end
```

And the example I refer is the [https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/110632-how-to-increment-a-variable]

Comment: please share your code with us with an example

Comment: Short question, why are you setting `i=001` and not just `i=1`. Nevertheless, inside your loop you are setting `t=t+dt` just to overwrite it 5 lines later. Why are you delaying the entire time series of `t` and not just the first starting point?. Please add a minimum example of the loaded matData.time and front_velocity.

Comment: i=001 is just simply because I need to read 300 files, eventually matlab still read i=1. What you mean by _inside your loop you are setting t=t+dt just to overwrite it 5 lines later_? I planned to plot the first row for t and v to ensure everything works fines then only process the rest using loop. Regarding the example of loaded matData.time is just simple read the data from mat file which 'matFileName = sprintf('%s.mat', filename1);
matData = load(matFileName);'.

Comment: Inside the for-loop you have the following lines `t = t+dt;` and  `t = matData.time;` So the question is why are you first delaying the entire time vector `t` by `dt` and after five lines you overwrite this without having used it. It is clear that you are reading in some data, I asked you to give a minimum example of your data e.g.: `t=[ 0 .05 ...etc]` and for `f_v=...`, this helps for debugging.

Comment: For the _t=t+dt_ is to set t will increase 0.05 for loop, and _t = matData.time_ is to read the data from workspace as there were total 301 columns, is a mistake that I didn't type it in row and column form. `t=[0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2,.....15]` and `f_v=[0.0301,0.0602,0.09020.1893...]`. The variables, t and v are 301 rows by 1 column.

Answer (score 0):

I reduced your example to the essential parts.

```
istart = 2;
iend = 301;
counter=istart;

%load data
% filename1 = 'front_data';
% matFileName = sprintf('%s.mat', filename1);
% matData = load(matFileName);
% t = matData.time;
% fv = matData.front_velocity;

%for demonstaration 
t=0:.05:15;
fv=rand(size(t));

for i = istart:iend
    %update
    time = t(istart:counter);
    values = fv(istart:counter);
    %plot
    plot(time,values,'*')
    %increase index
    counter=counter+1;
end
```

As you are loading always the same data in the loop you can do it once outside the loop, and for plotting you just update the length of your vector to be plotted. You could also just append the new value to the actual list.

Comment: The coding is work, unfortunately it did not plot according to sequence. I need to generate the plot respect to every time step to generate a movie to describe changes of v respect to t. The code above is randomly plotting. Any idea?